# Angular Inline Styling

Tags: angularjs

I am using $scope to set the background image of a div tag in my html using inline styling.

This is my code:

```
<div class="banner" style="background-image: url('{{bannerImage}}'), url('images/generic.jpg')"></div>
```

The scope works fine but I get this error in my console. 
`GET http://localhost:9000/%7B%7BbannerImage%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)`

Anyone have an idea what may be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ng-style` instead since you are outputting an expression. Using plain `style` won't make Angular evaluate the bindings.

Comment: I have tried this
`<div class="banner" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url({{bannerImage}})'}"></div>`

But I can't set a fallback image this way and the image is not replaced once the $scope variable is set. 

My image ends up being this: `background-image: url(http://localhost:9000/);`

Comment: You can write an expression that returns the static url for fallback image in case the variable is not set (or it's null, or empty)

Comment: I have also tried this:
`<div class="banner" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url({{bannerImage}})'}" style="background-image: url('images/generic.jpg');"></div>`

But it ends up becoming this:
`<div class="banner" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(images/Washington.jpg)'}" style="background-image: url(http://localhost:9000/);"></div>`

How can I write an expression to return a static url?

Comment: On controller:

`$scope.backgroundImageUrl = function() { return $scope.bannerImage? $scope.bannerImage : 'images/generic.jpg'`

On template:

`'background-image' : 'url({{backgroundImageUrl()}})'`

You can set that expression on template and avoid the function call on template. However, this can become a more complex logic that is hard to maintain/keep track on template side, but it's your call if you prefer.

Comment: I tried this:
`<div class="banner" ng-controller="bannerImageCtrl" ng-style='background-image' : 'url({{backgroundImageUrl()}})'></div>`

But backgroundImageUrl() does not run.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-style. May be it can help.